# Need regex pattern to capture pieces of formula

Tags: c#, regex

I need to extend a regex pattern in C#. The current pattern is capturing any multiplication or division in the formula:

```
([\+-]?\d+,*\d*[eE][\+-]?\d+|[\-\+]?\d+,*\d*)([\/\*])(-?\d+,*\d*[eE][\+-]?\d+|-?\d+,*\d*)
```

That means that if the expression is e.g. `12+18*3+4-3/3`, it will capture `18*3` and `-3/3`. That is great.

Now I need to extend it, so that it captures the following example: `12+18*3+4-3/3+10*mod8`. It should first capture `18*3`, then `-3/3`, as it did so far, but then it should capture `10mod8` (or `10*mod8`). How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: ... Why should it capture `-3/3`? In this case you're lucky and get `-1`, but what if it was `-3/-3`? You'd get 1, which would substitute in and you'd get `41`...

Comment: By the way - I'm not sure it's related, but I wrote an expression calculator once, and this isn't the way to go. Pretty soon you want `3^-3/2+5sinpi`, and a regex for that is crazy (my calculator can handle it, though). You may want to write a proper parser.

Comment: Besides the fact that regex is inappropriate here, you don't need to escape `-` (in your case), `+`, `/` and `*` inside your character classes.

Comment: regular expression are certainly not the best way to solve this problem. just look at how unwieldly your existing regexp is, and think how much easier that would've been to code, in C# or otherwise.

Comment: @Kobi: well, since "mod" is a string and not a standard operand, my code adds an asteriks before it. the reason for that is because the code converts "2(3+5)" into "2*(3+5)". i do realize that i should actually change the part of the code where those asterisks are added, but the code is not mine and i needed a quick way out. also, regex are VERY unknown to me.

Comment: @All: actually, i think that regex have shortened the coding here. i tried parsing the string using c# and it has turned out that the code was a true spaghetti. then i found the parser that uses regex and i liked it. the only part that was missing is the modulo. kobi was very kind to assist here (read the accepted answer below), so now i have everything covered. if you guys want the whole code to see, i'll be happy to send it to you.

Comment: i've found the original parser at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/MathParser.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the middle, you have `([\/\*])`.
Try changing it to `([/*]|\*?mod)` - this will accept `*`, `/`, `mod` and `*mod`

Comment: This is refreshing. Anonymous downvotes for a correct solution that answers the OP's question... Guess I should have been more educating :)

Comment: Sorry about that, it appears that was me, or better: my uncontrollable trigger-finger... I've undone the "mis-click"! :)

Comment: Kobi, you're the man! Thanks a bunch, it works like a charm. I've added my comment to the question's comments section with the explanation why I needed this functionality.

Comment: @Bart - that's cool, just virtual points. I think I took it well... :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot implement some sort of operator precedence in regex. Regex just matches, or it does not. Regex also cannot handle matching nested parenthesis. The only way to do this properly is to write an expression lexer/parser or define a [grammar and let a tool like ANTLR generate the lexer/parser for you](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Expression+evaluator).